# probability find minimum value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

X follow normal disributions with $ X~ N(40,20^2)$

i need to find a in $P(x>a)=0.95$ with $z_{0.05}=1.645$ from right tail table

it means

$P(Z \ge 1.645)=0.05 $ from table

im having trouble understand this,

$1-P(X \le a)= 0.95$

$P(X \le a)= 0.05$

how can i relate 
$P( Z \le \frac{a-40}{20})= 0.05$ and $P(Z \ge 1.645)=0.05 $  ?

how can i flip the symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Standard normal distribution $Z(x)$ is an even function. For all real $y$,

$\implies P(Z\le y)=P(Z\ge-y)$

Comment: Is $P(Z \ge y) = P(Z \le -y)$ too?

Comment: Yes, that is true as well. You can just substitute $m=-y$ to get $P(Z\ge m)=P(Z\le-m)$